# Unable to change RaisedButton color

Tags: dart, flutter

```
RaisedButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Text('Get in'), // change it to sign-in
          color: Colors.blue,
        )
```

I am creating this widget under children, but the color is not getting changed from its default grey color. I tried with hex code value but still no help.

Answer (score 24):

From RaisedButton documentation:

If the [onPressed] callback is null, then the button will be disabled and by default will resemble a flat button in the [disabledColor]. If you are
trying to change the button's [color] and it is not having any effect, check that you are passing a non-null [onPressed] handler.

Comment: Yes, I am using non-null handler. I thought it might be the reason. But why is that affecting? When I load my app, the button should come with the color I want. It shouldn't matter whether I press it or not (I am not using SplashColor).

Comment: because it uses disabledColor? I extended my answer

Comment: Thanks, once I pass a handler to  to onPressed param, I can see the color.

Comment: Man, I lost so many hours because of this. Thank you for your answer @jprogramista.

Answer (score 8):

RaisedButton color depends on is it onPress able or not like this one. You should add onPressed into the attribute

```
                           RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () => {},
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text(
                                'Login',
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                            ),
```

Comment: just onPressed: (){}, will be enough

Comment: oh i didn't notice. I think they only add disabledColor parm

Answer (score 7):

Use this instead,

```
 RaisedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Text('Get in'), // change it to sign-in
              color: Colors.blue,
              disabledColor: Colors.blue,//add this to your code
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before, the solution is removing the null keyword from onPressed method to some implementation , at least this : () {}